# Text box to allow only decimal numbers, delete and backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code that works fine for decimal numbers allowing only two digits after the decimal. My question is how to modify the code to :

1. Allow backspace and delete And
2. How to make the code dynamic so that it does not use the `id` attribute instead pass the element in the method on the html and accept and use that element in `javascript`/`jquery`.

Here is my code:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt, element) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  else {
    var len = $('#rate').val().length;
    var index = $('#rate').val().indexOf('.');

    if (index > 0 && charCode == 46) {
      return false;
    }
    if (index > 0) {
      var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index;
      if (CharAfterdot > 3) {
        return false;
      }
    }

  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="rate" name="rate" placeholder="Billing Rate" required onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Adding the code here for anyone who would be having the same requirements as I had.

```js
/*
 *  Function to allow decimal numbers to be entered in the text box
 *   - allows integers, backspace and delete
 *   - does not allow alphabets
 *   - allows only one decimal point
 *   - allows only two digits after decimal point
 */
function isNumberKey(evt, element) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : window.event.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && !(charCode == 46 || charCode == 8))
    return false;
  else {
    var len = $(element).val().length;
    var index = $(element).val().indexOf('.');
    if (index > 0 && charCode == 46) {
      return false;
    }
    if (index > 0) {
      var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index;
      if (CharAfterdot > 3) {
        return false;
      }
    }

  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="rate" name="rate" placeholder="Billing Rate" required onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your `textbox`, say `number` here and below code will do it for you:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yufc53g8/)**

```
$('.number').on('keypress',function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

> **Note: Your code was not allowing to enter `.` in textbox**

Comment: I want to make my code dynamic, so that it can be used on any html element. Don't want to hard code any attribute value.

Comment: This works on all the `input` elements which has class `number`! By **Dynamic** how would you describe it here?